# How is faster-than-light communication achieved in "Away"?

Tags: away

Most of the technology in [*Away*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Away_(TV_series)) (2020) is just a small extrapolation of today's technology. For example, they are still using chemical rockets instead of, e.g., nuclear ones. They still use bulky, uncomfortable hard-shell space suits instead of mechanical counter pressure suits.

In the pilot, it is mentioned that the lunar base is melting water from the lunar pole to pump into the spacecraft for radiation shielding, so they don't even have "magic" shielding, a la Andrew Weir's *The Martian*.

There is no artificial gravity, no AI running the ship, and no ubiquitous robots.

In almost all aspects, their technology is only slightly more advanced than ours; in some aspects, it even feels like a step backwards. (E.g., we *do* have experimental robots on the ISS.)

There is one exception, though: they obviously have faster-than-light communication, which is not "just" a *huge* leap forward from our current technologies, but in fact physically and mathematically *impossible* based on our current understanding of the universe.

However, I do not remember any explanation as to *how* this is achieved. (Unlike, e.g., the radiation shielding, which the writers felt was important enough to explain that they put it in the pilot episode.)

Is any explanation given about how they achieve faster-than-light communication?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237325/is-the-communication-technology-in-away-ever-explained

Comment: (Unlike e.g. the radiation shielding, which the writers felt important enough to explain that they put it in the pilot episode.) - this becomes a plot point later in the series

Answer (score 3):

There's a huge difference between a story that claims to have faster-than-light communication, and a story that simply omits the delay from sublight communication because it hinders the flow of the scenes and doesn't add anything of value.

Away seems to be an example of the latter case. There is no mention of FTL communication that I can find, and the communication we do see would've been unchanged (plotwise) even if there had been a delay between each message.